# Is AUC for binary predictor equal to balanced accuracy?

Tags: binary-data, accuracy, auc

... because they come up the same when I compute them for binary predictions. So either they are the same, or I have something wrongly implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. According to [the paper for AUC for binary predictors](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.04881.pdf) it really is the same, at least in R, as it computes the AUC with ties.